# How RTSP stream works at low FPS

Tags: video, ffmpeg, frame, rtsp, decoding

I am ingesting many RTSP streams on a single device using `pyav` (Pythonic binding for FFmpeg). Please, note that I am not an expert on video protocols so I might use some terms improperly. I thank you for the patience.

I am ingesting many RTSP on a single device. Because of this, I cannot process all the video streams at their original camera FPS (e.g. 24 FPS). Instead, I can just process them at a lower FPS (e.g. 3 FPS). What happens when a camera is recording at an higher FPS than the one I am consuming the video at? Am I simply loosing data (`24-3=21 FPS of data is dropped`) or does RTSP recompute some data (like `I` `P` frames) to adapt to my ingestion speed (3 FPS)? In particular, I would like to understand what happens to the `motion vectors` associated to the h264 encoding. Am I losing some of them, or are they recomputed by the source since I am consuming the video at 3 FPS?

Comment: What is the source of the streams? What are the specs of the device (CPU, GPU, memory, etc.)?

Comment: The source can be any kind of camera streaming on RTSP to my device. With "my device" I refer to a generic pc running ubuntu. Note that I don't really need increase the FPS, instead I would like to understand what happen when the source and the consumer FPS are not the same. I am trying to understand how the RTSP protocol works in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

RTSP is just a transport. It does not do anything to the data stream. If you have a camera set to 24 FPS, it will send 24 FPS.

If you throw frames away, you will only want to throw away non-IDR frames. Once you throw a frame away, you must wait until you get another IDR (possibly preceded by SPS, PPS and SEI) to resume decoding. Non-IDR frames depend on previous frames. So once you throw one away, if you try to pass another non-IDR to ffmpeg, it will not decode properly and the image will be corrupted.

If you throw away 21 out of 24 frames, it won't look much different than a 1 frame per second stream.

On a decent PC with a Xeon processor using the h264_cuvid decoder, I can decode 64 low resolution streams (352x240) at 24 FPS.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know what `ffmpeg` does when, in Python, I consume just a few number of frames per second? Does it throw away the intermediate frames or does it decode them and return only the last one (or does it do anything else)?

Comment: I am not familiar with the Python interface for ffmpeg. I use the C interface. Can you post your code?

Comment: `pyav` is just a wrapper for `libav` which is then used by `ffmpeg`; see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67594208/pyav-libav-ffmpeg-what-happens-when-frame-from-live-source-are-not-processed