# pyav / libav / ffmpeg what happens when frame from live source are not processed fast enough

Tags: ffmpeg, rtsp, frame-rate, libav, pyav

I am using `pyav` to process a live RTSP stream:

```
import av
import time

URL = "RTSP_url"
container = av.open(
            url, 'r',
            options={
                'rtsp_transport': 'tcp',
                'stimeout': '5000000',
                'max_delay': '5000000',
            }
        )

for packet in self.container.demux(video=0):
    for frame in packet.decode():
        # do something
        time.sleep(10)
```

What happens if I `do something` too slow? Are frames / packets dropped or are they buffered?

I guess the same question would apply to `libav` or `ffmpeg`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience gstreamer could store in a buffer old frames and return them even minutes later. Not sure if PyAv would do the same.

Answer (score 1):

`tcp` is a guaranteed delivery protocol with built-in flow control. If you do not process the incoming data as fast as it is received, the `tcp` stack will buffer the data until its buffers are full at which time the `tcp` protocol will let the sender know that it cannot receive any more data. If this continues, the sender's output buffers will eventually fill up and then it is up to the sender to decide what to do.

An IP camera at that point may throw frames away or it may even drop the connection. Most IP cameras also use a keep-alive mechanism typically via RTCP packets sent over the RTSP stream. The camera may send Sender Reports and the receiver should send back Receiver Reports. If the camera does not get a Receiver Report within a timeout, it will drop the connection. I would have to assume that either the `av` library or `ffmpeg` is doing that.

You probably do not want to do `time.sleep(10)`.

If you really feel that you need to discard packets, then you could examine your packets before calling `decode` to see if you are falling behind. If you are getting too far behind, you can discard packets that are not key frames until you catch up. The effect will be that the video will have jumps in it.

Comment: Do you think it is possible that the camera compute P-frames and B-frames according to the amount of frames that the receiver is consuming?

Comment: I am not sure but I know some cameras may adjust the quality to get better compression if you configure them for VBR (Variable Bit Rate). I don't know of any cameras that modify the frame rate or key frame interval on the fly.

Comment: Ok. So basically, given an unknown camera, there's no way to know in advance what happens if my code cannot process the images fast enough, right? I mean, the `time.sleep(10)` is an exaggeration, but even a task that takes a few milliseconds, repeat thousands of times, could lead to non real-time processing.

Comment: If you are only displaying live streams, you shouldn't need to do a sleep at all. The camera will deliver the frames in real time and I would assume that `demux` is doing the wait for packet for you. And I also assume that each camera connection is on its own thread.

Comment: I am not doing a `sleep`. The `sleep` is just representing a task that might take something like `0.2` seconds (i.e. 5 frames per second). Since the camera is probably recording at 24 fps I am wondering what will happen to the 24-5=19 frames of delay. From your answer it seems that they will be buffered and then, once the buffer is full, it will be up to the camera. Any chance that the camera sync with me and sends me 5 fps by automatically dropping the remaining 19? I am afraid that my software will keep processing old data because of the buffer